# Problem on upgrade from 11.10 to 12.4 with CD

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, installation, upgrade

I write the Ubuntu 12.4 .iso file to CD. reboot my PC and boot from CD and chose install Ubuntu. I don't know why the chosen "upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 " is disable ?
is problem in my hardware? 
I read all the page for this upgrade on the internet but none of this worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not see an upgrade button unless you bring up Update Manager.  Below are different ways that can help you in your process.

Use this method if the system being upgraded is not connected to the Internet. To upgrade using a CD or DVD [See Upgrading Using the Alternate CD/DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades)

Otherwise you can

From the desktop Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in `update-manager`

Or

For servers:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
do-release-upgrade
```

First check for updates, then Install them, and finally click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

[image]

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades for details.

Comment: my question is "why (upgrade Ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.4) is disable?" ?where is problem?also I do according to page that you introduce but when I insert CD and run "gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"" see nothing!?

Comment: Did you download the right CD?

Comment: yes, I download the .iso file from ubuntu.com and version is 32bit

Comment: I know, but did you download the **Alternate install CD**?

Comment: I download from [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) page.where I should download Alternate install CD?is there difference  between that  I downloaded thing and you say?

Comment: Download from the link I included in the answer **See Upgrading Using the Alternate CD/DVD**