# Upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, release-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem on upgrade from 11.10 to 12.4 with CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147707/problem-on-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-4-with-cd)

Hello !

After installing and checking few times for packages that are not in Ubuntu 11.10.  I decides to upgrade to version 12.04LTS.  But I can`t find an "Upgrade" button.  And of course the sentence 'New Ubuntu release 12.04LTS is available'. What is a wrong here?  How can I upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

You will not see an upgrade button unless you bring up Update Manager.  Below are different ways that can help you in your process.

Use this method if the system being upgraded is not connected to the Internet. To upgrade using a CD or DVD [See Upgrading Using the Alternate CD/DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades)

Otherwise you can

From the desktop Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in `update-manager`

Or

For servers:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
do-release-upgrade
```

First check for updates, then Install them, and finally click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

[image]

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades for details.

Comment: I made some (small) edits to your excellent answer. first , with update-manager, -d updates to a development release. Now that 12.04 has been released, that would be 12.01. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/update-manager.8.html Second, your apt-get command does not upgrade to 12.04. upgrading by apt-get is not advised, use  update-manager-core